# Tikzposter background color

Tags: color, backgrounds, tikzposter

I'm trying to modify the standard 'Desert' theme in tizkposter by changing the backgroud colour of the blocks to white and the poster background colour to the gray that is already set as a backgroud for the blocks, that is, switching both colours. However, I can set the first to white but I can't change the second to ANY colour.

```
\usetheme{Desert}

% OTHER COLOUR ADJUSTMENTS:
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{gray}

\begin{document}
some blocks and their text...
\end{document}
```

Any idea of how to achieve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `backgroundcolor` is for the `Default` background style:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Desert}

%% OTHER COLOUR ADJUSTMENTS:
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{gray}


\usebackgroundstyle{Default}

 \begin{document}
     \maketitle  % See Section 4.1
     \block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}  % See Section 4.2
     \begin{columns}  % See Section 4.4
         \column{0.3}  % See Section 4.4
         \block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
         \column{0.7}
         \block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
         \note{Notetext}  % See Section 4.3
     \end{columns}
 \end{document}
```

As an alternative: create new background style

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Desert}

%% OTHER COLOUR ADJUSTMENTS:
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{gray}


\definebackgroundstyle{mystyle}{
    \draw[line width=0pt, bottom color=backgroundcolor, top
     color=backgroundcolor!60!white] (bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
    \draw[draw=none, line width=0pt, bottom color=titlebgcolor, top
     color=framecolor] (bottomleft) rectangle ($(bottomleft)+(\textwidth,3)$);
}

\usebackgroundstyle{mystyle}

 \begin{document}
     \maketitle  % See Section 4.1
     \block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}  % See Section 4.2
     \begin{columns}  % See Section 4.4
         \column{0.3}  % See Section 4.4
         \block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
         \column{0.7}
         \block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
         \note{Notetext}  % See Section 4.3
     \end{columns}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works well, however the colored stripe at the bottom does not appear anymore. Is there any way I can keep it? Thanks.

Comment: @PauRiera Please test second code